# web3.js-1.0.0 General Availability (GA) Date ?

Tags: web3js, web3j

When will web3js 1.0.0 be General Available? i.e., web3 GA date

Comment: To my knowledge, no such date has been announced.

Comment: thanks smarx! You are really a great person. I like to check with you if you might have any answer to this question - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51742/quorum-track-state-variable-changes-in-struct-data-lineage

Comment: FYI, web3.py and web3.js releases are not synchronized. So I removed the web3py tag. I can't say for sure about web3j, but I suspect that's also independently developed.